# Помогите сделать эффект виньетки в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image]

Как сделать такой же эффект, как на фото. Уже очень долго ищу

Comment: В простом случае можно взять текстуру с радиальным градиентом и растянуть на весь экран.

Answer (score 0):

в гугл вбил "vignette unity" и первая же ссылка ведет на документацию юнити: [https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Vignette.html#:~:text=The%20Vignette%20effect%20darkens%20the,the%20center%20of%20an%20image](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessing-Vignette.html#:%7E:text=The%20Vignette%20effect%20darkens%20the,the%20center%20of%20an%20image).

на страницу с постпроцессингом виньетки

Но в общем-то никто не мешает взять текстуру с альфаканалом и добавить на камеру в режиме оверлей